# See how a changed uncommitted git file looked like before changes

Tags: git

Let's say I have a file `target.json` and I've made changes to it in number of places. It is one of many files that already existed in the repo which I've changed since the last commit. These files could be staged or not.

To see the changes made to the file I can do:

```
git diff target.json
```

This mostly shows the deltas on the file. What if I wanted to see the version of the file before I made the current local changes? That is, browse the file as of the latest `commit`. `diff` adds a lot of noise and makes it hard to see the file before changes. I also can't think/find a flag on `blame` that would do what I'm looking for. I can think of the following ways:

- `stash` the changes, view `target.json`, and then `pop` the `stash`. I've done this in the past.
- `commit` the changes, `checkout` the previous `commit`, view `target.json`, remove the latest `commit`. This seems ugly.
- Make a copy of `target.json`, remove the changes done to the file, view the file, `mv` the copy to `target.json`. This also sounds like something I may have done in the past.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Feel like I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Most good IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ) have Git plugins, which, among other things, can show the before and after of a modified file.

Comment: That's true, I should look into doing this on my IDE. But there should be an easy way to do so on the terminal

Comment: There probably is a way to do this via the terminal, but that's not the tool I would want to use here.  Poke around SO and you might find an answer to your question.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the help. Nice secret hat btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show HEAD:target.json` will print out the contents of the file `target.json` contained in the commit identified by `HEAD`.  Similarly, `git show hash:target.json` will show the contents of the file `target.json` contained in the specified *`hash`*.  See [the `git rev-parse` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) for a complete list of ways to spell specific commits; most of these work here.

`git show :target.json` will print out the contents of the file `target.json` contained in the index (aka staging area); this is useful if it differs from both `HEAD:target.json` and the work-tree file named `target.json`.

During a conflicted merge, the index / staging-area will hold (up to) *three* copies of `target.json` and you can access them as `1:target.json` (merge base version), `2:target.json` (`HEAD` or `--ours` version), and `3:target.json` (`--theirs` version).  This is more or less how `git mergetool` works as well: it extracts all three to temporary files.  (It uses `git checkout-index --all --temp` rather than `git show`, as that's more suited to its scripted code, but the principle is the same.)

Note: if you have CRLF modification and/or a smudge filter defined in `.gitattributes` or similar, `git show` used to not apply these.  Modern Git can be told *do use them* (`--textconv`) or *do not use them* (`--no-textconv`) but in general should do the sensible thing by default.

Comment: Beautiful! Just what I was looking for. Tried `git show HEAD target.json` before posting, would've never thought of using `:`

Comment: That particular syntax would be pretty reasonable, if `git show` didn't take a *list* of things to show (`git show <item1> <item2> <item3>` will try to locate and show each of these in turn). You can tell from the SYNOPSIS section of the documentation pages here, though.